# GUI automation with pywinauto. Double clicking item in a list with no name

Tags: python, user-interface, automation, pywinauto

I am trying to automate a self made GUI in python with pywinauto.
I am starting the application with `app = Application().start(...)` and get the window with `dlg = app.top_window_()`.

In the next step I want to double-click an item from a list. But I do not know how.
I tried to use the Inspect.exe. By clicking on "navigate to children" I get the list which has no name. Clicking again on "navigate to children" shows the name of the item I want to click.

So, how can I refer to this item? 
I thought about something like `dlg.itemname.double_click(button='left')`? I can only find examples in which they are pressing menu entries.

Answer (score 4):

From what you're describing I can assume you use `Application(backend="uia")` (or must use) because `Inspect.exe` uses UI Automation technology which is supported by UIA backend in pywinauto.

And yes, you're almost right about double click. This should look so:

```
dlg.itemname.double_click_input(button='left')
# or
dlg.itemname.click_input(button='left', double=True)
```

How would I know? Detecting items as separate controls are typical for UIA backend.

For default Win32 backend (what you can see in Spy++ tool) a list view or a list box always have virtual items that are accessible by wrapper methods only, not as separate controls.